# Using printwriter with google analytics api to generate CSV file

Tags: java, csv, google-analytics, filewriter

Hi all i am using the google analytics api to export some queries to a CSV i am currently having issues with using this code

```
 PrintWriter pw = null;
   try {
     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.csv")));
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

it keeps telling me that

"Multiple markers at this line

- The method BufferedWriter(FileWriter) is undefined for the type HelloAnalyticsApiSample
- Duplicate local variable pw"

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.csv")));
```

Comment: ok that fixed it thanks. do you mind showing me how to incorporate that pw into this code
  if (results.getRows() == null || results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("No results Found.");
    } else {

      // Print column headers.
      for (ColumnHeaders header : results.getColumnHeaders()) {
        System.out.printf(header.getName() + ", ");
      }
      System.out.println();
// Print actual data.
      for (List<String> row : results.getRows()) {
        for (String column : row) {
          System.out.printf(column + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();

Comment: That's a matter for a new question entirely but before you do take a look at [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) which manages the reading & writing  of CSVs in Java :)